# Warum sächselt Erich Honecker, obwohl er aus dem Saarland kommt?

Tags: dialect, history

In all the speeches and interviews I know, [Erich Honecker](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Honecker) is speaking with what seems to me a notably east German accent (Apologies if "Sächseln" isn't entirely correct. I don't know much about east German accents and the differences and subtleties they certainly have.)

[Example on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gFkcWeo1Gk&NR=1)

However, according to the Wikipedia article, he was born in [Neunkirchen (Saar)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Honecker) where he spent his entire childhood and youth. Arguably, that time is usually when your accent is defined and that place is about as far from the east as its gets.

Why is he speaking with an eastern German accent then?

The only explanation that I have is that adopting a bit of local colour was a political act in the GDR, as an act of differentiation from the West.

Is this correct?

Comment: Also laut http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialekte_im_Saarland#Akzeptanz handelt es sich wohl um einen saarländischen Dialekt – oder zumindest um ein Überbleibsel.

Comment: @MusiKk ohoo, sehr interessant! Das hätte ich nicht gedacht.

Comment: It's not so easy to tell apart these two dialects. I came to Saarbrücken mid 1991, shortly after reunification. Initially I thought those were all people who had emigrated from the former east Germany (although there were a few it was not true in general).

Comment: Video link sadly no longer working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der sächsische und der saarländische Dialekt ähneln sich einfach - vermutlich nicht aufgrund gemeinsamer Wurzeln, sondern eher zufällig - in einigen Punkten:

So kann man als Faustformel zur Erzeugung eines sächsischen Klangspektrums (nicht eines wirklich originalen Dialekts - definitiv soll hier niemandem zu nahe getreten werden) - probiert es aus! - alle Vokale durch ihre Umlaute ersetzen und alle stimmlosen Konsonanten durch ihre stimmhaften Versionen. "Tastatur" wird zu "Däsdädür", "Kuchen" zu "Güchen", "Taschenuhr" zu "Däschenühr" und so weiter. Zudem werden einige Konsonanten eher weich ausgesprochen (etwa im bekannten "Gänsefleisch", das eigentlich "Können Sie vielleicht [den Kofferraum aufmachen]?" meint).

Nun gibt es im Saarländischen ebenfalls einerseits viele Umlaute und andererseits "weiche" Konsonanten (s. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saarl%C3%A4ndischer_Dialekt#Beispiele oder http://www.reinhard-buerck.de/waltraud_schwambach/misc/saarland/woerterbuch/a.htm) - Beispiele:

> Ei isch gehn emmòòl gugge (Ich sehe (also) mal nach)

oder

> Un dann hann isch’s gefròòt, ob’s noch Luschd hätt. – Ei nää! (Dann fragte ich sie, ob sie noch Lust habe. – Nein!)

Auch wenn es wahrscheinlich mehr Unterschiede als Gemeinsamkeiten zwischen beiden Dialekten gibt, genügen diese Ähnlichkeiten offenbar, um das ungeübte Ohr hinreichend zu täuschen.

Die zusätzliche Tatsache, dass man einerseits Honecker eher mit der DDR als mit dem Saarland und andererseits die DDR durchaus mit dem sächsischen Dialekt assoziiert, verfestigt den in der Frage beschriebenen Eindruck des "Sächselns".

Comment: Sehr interessant - ich werde mich mal nach Videobeispielen für Saarländisch umschauen, um den Unterschied besser zu verstehen. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Vielleicht auch Intensivtraining unter Walter Ulbricht? ;)